# Grouping matching strings in array

Tags: c#, csv, grouping

I have a code where I have loaded values from a csv file into multiple arrays, and the arrays have a lot of duplicates. Is there a way I can group these duplicates together?

```
string headerLine = sr.ReadLine();
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var values = line.Split(',');

    var clients = values[0];
    var backup = float.Parse(values[10]);
    var subtotal = float.Parse(values[15]);
    
    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        if ()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like removing totally irrelevant tags (like the C language tag, C and C# are two *very* different languages).

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample input and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: i have a lot of duplicates like:
word,
word,
word,
multiple words,
multiple words,
multiple words.
Can i somehow group them and get some sort of count?

Comment: Sort the arrays.  Then the duplicates will be adjacent

Comment: @stark if you use a hash there will be no need for sorting